# Why is `Promise.then()` being executed before finishing `Promise.all()`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise

I want to execute code after a list of files is created but that code is being executed before.

Check the comments in the following psudo code for better understanding.

**Pseudo Code:**

```
var fs = require('fs');

Promise.all([
    fs.writeFile(...),
    list.forEach(element => {      // I think the problem is here
        fs.writeFile(...);         // The files content is big
        console.log(element.name); // This is printing after then() method
    })
]).then((v) => {
    console.log(v); // This is printing before the files being created
});
```

I hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does Promise.all() return a Promise ?

Comment: Assuming that all of the array elements in the `all` argument are themselves promises, this should work.  Hard to say without seeing the real code.

Comment: Because you're not providing promises to Promise.all.

Comment: @estus yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` expect an array of Promise. If what you pass in the array is not a Promise, it will be resolved immediately.

`fs.writeFile` does *not* return a Promise, it is a nodeJS function that expect a callback of the form `(err, result)`. You can use `util.promisify` to make it a function returning a Promise.

Your second argument is even less a Promise, as it is just a `forEach`. It can be addressed by returning instead another `Promise.all` of `list.map(...)` where the mapping function return a promise.

Comment: I got confused by the "more text than code" but you are right

Answer (score 1):

The `Promise` returned by `Promise.all()` will be resolved if all promises that you passed to it are resolved.

Note that fs.writeFile does not return promises, but you could use the [fs Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) by importing

```
var fs = require('fs').promises
```

instead (but beware it's experimental).

But then you would still only pass one promise: `fs.writeFile(...)`.

`list.forEach(...)` does not return a `Promise` so `Promise.all()` can't wait for it.

Try something like (pseudo code):

```
Promise.all([
    fs.writeFile(...),
    ...list.map(element => { // convert list to an array of promises
        console.log(element.name); 
        return fs.writeFile(...);   
    })
]).then((v) => {
    console.log(v);
});
```

Comment: `fs.writeFile(...)` isn't a promise either.

Comment: @estus It seems that that there actually is a promise based API: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

Comment: Yes, there is, but only since Node 10.

Comment: @sloth You can be using bluebird to return fs a promise.

const writeFile = require("bluebird").promisify(fs.writeFile);
writeFile()
.then(()=>{
//Do something here
})

Answer (score 1):

Using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) promisify, we can get a promise return.

```
const writeFile = require("bluebird").promisify(fs.writeFile);

Promise.all([
    fs.writeFile(...),
    ...list.map(element => {
        console.log(element.name); 
        return writeFile(...);   
    })
]).then((v) => {
    console.log(v);
});
```

Comment: I find all the answers helpful but this one works in all NodeJs versions so i'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: Note that you can directly use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original), which has been supported for a while, without installing any third-party dependencies.

Comment: @AnthonyGarcia Oh yes, you are totally right! Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference I am demonstrating a way to make any asynchronous function to a promise.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const writeFile = function(file, data, options){
    new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, options, (err) => {
            if(err){
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

Now you can use this `writeFile` function as following

```
writeFile(filePath, data, options)
    .then(() => {
        // operation successful, handle your logic here
    }).catch((e) => {
        // something is wrong, handle the error here.
    });
```

Once you know how the promise works, then its really simple to convert async functions.

To use this function in `Promise.all` we can do the following-

```
Promise.all([
    writeFile(...), // pass your arguments here
    ...list.map(element => { // convert list to an array of promises
        // use the function to create a promise as following, 
        // make sure to match the arguments as per your need 

        return writeFile(element.filePath, element.data, element.options);
    })
]).then((v) => {
    console.log(v);
});
```

To summarize what is going on here, we are creating an array of promises and passing it to the `Promise.all` function. And we are creating the array of promises using a base function `writeFile` which returns a promise and resolves after the file is written. We are using es6 spread operator `...` to spread the elements of `list` object.

I hope this might help someone in future.